# How to pass value from controller to html in angular 1.4.4

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to pass a value which I am getting in response to calling REST service from my controller to my view(which is in HTML). But it says "vm is not defined at errorCallback (configuration.controller.js?c133:21)". Below is my code snippet. What am I missing?

Here is my Controller

```
  /*@ngInject*/
    constructor($rootScope, ConfigurationService){
    Object.assign(this, {$rootScope, ConfigurationService});
        this.name = 'configuration';
        let vm = this;
        vm.scheduleTimePeriod = 10;
        vm.dataTTL = 20;
    }

    loadData() {
      this.ConfigurationService.getConfigurationDetails().then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
        vm.scheduleTimePeriod = response.scheduleTimePeriod;
        vm.dataTTL = response.dataTTL;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log("error response: ", response.statusText);
        });
    }
}

export default ConfigurationController;
```

Here is my HTML view page

```
<form class="form-horizontal exampleForm" ng-init="vm.loadData()">
      <div class="form-group required">
           <label class="control-label" for="datattl">Data TTL</label>
           <input ng-model="vm.dataTTL" id="datattl" name="datattl" type="text" class="form-control" style="width:100%;" required>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group required">
       <label class="control-label" for="scheduletimeperiod">Schedule Timeperiod</label>
       <input ng-bind="vm.scheduleTimePeriod" id="scheduletimeperiod" name="scheduletimeperiod" type="text" class="form-control" style="width:100%;" required>
       </div>

       <div class="cf clearRow">
       <button ng-click="vm.postRequest()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
       </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: `let vm` does not declare a variable gloabally; that's what the error is saying, `vm` is not defined on the callback's scope.

Comment: Ok. Then what I need to do to achieve my goal? @LenilsondeCastro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is in load data function

```
     loadData() {
       const vm = this;
      this.ConfigurationService.getConfigurationDetails().then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
        vm.scheduleTimePeriod = response.scheduleTimePeriod;
        vm.dataTTL = response.dataTTL;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log("error response: ", response.statusText);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the "Controller as vm" approach. This means that your view will be able to directly reference the controller instance as the "vm" variable. Now that this is clear, let's have a look at your code.

Your problem is that currently you are defining the `vm` variable directly in the controller constructor. Since typescript has well defined variable scopes, that variable **does not exist** outside the controller scope. As a result, when you try to access it in the  loadData function you receive an error, because `vm` no longer exist.

As others mentioned, one possible solution is to just redefine the vm variable inside the method.

That said, you don't need the variable in the first place.

"VM" is not a magical variable that you **have to** use in the controller in order for things to word. The "Controller as" pattern is just what it says on the thin - a pattern that allows you to access your controller ("exported/visible" parts) from the view, by giving it an alias. By itself, the name "vm" does not bear any meaning - "vm" is just a shorthand for "view-model" and that why most samples uses that name for the controller.

Let's look at a sample ([courtesy of John Papa](https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/))

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('Customers', [function() {
      var vm = this;
      vm.title = 'Customers';
      vm.customers = [
         {name: 'Haley'}, {name: 'Ella'}, {name: 'Landon'}, {name: 'John'}
      ];
}]);
```

As you can see, back in the Javascript world, a controller was just a function. For this reason, people preferred to explicitly define the vm variable and assign the controller properties / function to it.

**But you are using Typescript.**
Because of this, you probably should avoid defining the `vm` variable in your controller in the first place. Since your controller is now a typescript class, it is probably much clearer to just define the variables / methods directly in the controller.

Your code would become something similar to this:

```
export default class ConfigurationController implements angular.IController {
    name: string;
    scheduleTimePeriod : number;
    dataTTL : number;


    constructor(private $rootScope, private ConfigurationService){    
        this.name = 'configuration';

        this.scheduleTimePeriod = 10;
        this.dataTTL = 20;
    }

    $onInit?(): void {
        // required if you use the angular.IController interface from the Angularjs type definitions. You can ignore this method if that's not the case.
    }

    public loadData(): void {
      this.ConfigurationService.getConfigurationDetails()
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            this.scheduleTimePeriod = response.scheduleTimePeriod;
            this.dataTTL = response.dataTTL;
        }, (response) => {
            console.log("error response: ", response.statusText);
        });
    }
}
```